# Issue with CSS Media Queries(Cannot get rid from empty space)

Tags: css, media-queries

I am really new to Css. I'm using @media to get two different headings for my interfaces's mobile view and desktop view.By using @media i hide the headings when changing the views but it still displays the other one's content space.As example, This is my mobile view
[image: This is my mobile view]

Mobile view has the desktop views heading space in top.
This is my code.

```
#css
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {

    .desktopViewFirstRow{
        visibility: hidden;
        display: none;
    }

<Grid.Row className="desktopViewFirstRow">
        <Grid.Column width={8}>User</Grid.Column>
        <Grid.Column width={4}>
          <Button className="redButton">Delete</Button>
        </Grid.Column>
      </Grid.Row>
```

Thank you.

Comment: did you try white-space:nowrap; ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    .desktopViewFirstRow{
        visibility: hidden;
        display: none !important;
    }
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You are using both **visibility** and **display** properties.

**Visibility** will hide the element but leaves the space of the element in UI.
on the otherhand,
**display** will remove the element from the UI and also its space.

**Note:-** Both **visibility** and **display** properties will not remove the elements from the DOM, just they will hide and show the elements in UI.

Now, as per your query, Based on your requirement use any one of the properties.
As you want to remove the heading along with the space, remove visibility property and use only display property.

```
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {

    .desktopViewFirstRow{
        display: none;
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the min-width. When you use this and write AND, you are applying this rule for both instances. Try with this one. No need to have a minimum if you want this to apply for mobile phones, this should work fine.
Also you need to remove 'visibility : hidden'. As  this only hides the element and doesn't remove its space, unlike display:none.

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {

  .desktopViewFirstRow {
    display: none;
  }
```